# how to access abstract class inside an interface

Tags: java, android, oop

this is more of a java question rather than an android question. If we look at the code below, I need to access getEnrollmentUsername from my main class:

```
public interface IAirWatchSDKService extends android.os.IInterface {

    public String getEnrollmentUsername(String publicKey);

    public abstract static class Stub extends Binder implements IAirWatchSDKService {

        private static class Proxy implements IAirWatchSDKService {
            @Override
            public IBinder asBinder() {
                return null;
            }

            public String getEnrollmentUsername(String publicKey){

                return "it worked";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the problem is that it is wrapped inside of an abstract class. How can I get to it from my main class? And none of this code can change because it is part of a library, rather I need to write code from my main class only.

Comment: You need to make the class visible to the main class: depending on where the main class is, you should make it default, protected or public - not private.

Comment: You can't, because the inner class is `private`. You could create a `static` instance of `Proxy` in the `Stub` class and then use a getter to retrieve it. It all depends on your needs.

Comment: And none of this code can change because it is part of a library

Answer (score 1):

`Proxy` is declared as a private class. To access it from outside it needs `public`, `protected` or default(package private) depending on where you want to access it from.

Comment: Then you would just be able to call the method on an instance of a Proxy object.

Comment: `import whatever.packagename.IAirWatchSDKService.Stub.Proxy;`, then refer to it as `Proxy`.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is that if your main class needs to run this method, it should implement the interface. That, or the main class is aware of the interface with a method such as this: `myIAirWatchSDKService.getEnrollmentUsername(s)`